# jquery add and remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigational menu now how can i add a selected class after click to any of my spans and remove selected class from previous span using Jquery.

```html
<div class="large-12 columns TSCSlot">
    <div class="large-10 columns DayRow">
        <div class="large-12 columns left DaySelected">
            <span class="Selected"></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>                      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('div.large-12.columns.left.DaySelected > span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
    $(this).closest('span').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
span.Selected {
    background-color: #5e9e37 !important;
    color: white !Important;
}
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When near identical answers are posted, is is SO etiquette to accept the earliest (unless there is a good reason not to) :)

Comment: Sorry didnt know that, ticked your answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of your click *is* the span, so `closest('span')` will find itself, so your following `find('.selected')` will not find the "selected" element:

Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6pg5as4n/

```
$(this).closest('.DaySelected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Html:

```
<div class="large-12 columns TSCSlot">
    <div class="large-10 columns DayRow">
        <div class="large-12 columns left DaySelected">
            <span class="selected"></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>
            <span class=""></span>                      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- Using `closest` with `.DaySelected` will ensure you do not modify other controls on the page. Your could also just use `parent()` e.g. `$(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected')`
- The second line then just adds the `selected` class to the clicked `span`.
- You have an uppercase `S` on `selected` in the html. Have changed that to lowercase `s` to match the code.
- You do not appear to need to prevent propagation and spans have no default operation to prevent. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6pg5as4n/1/
- Instead of `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation` you can simply `return false` to do *both*. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6pg5as4n/2/

Answer (score 1):

As You telling in post. You are clicking the current span You can add selected class ,remaining selected class are removed

```
$('div.large-12.columns.left.DaySelected > span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
    $('.Selected').removeClass('Selected');
    $(this).addClass('Selected');
});
```

NOTE :in css Selected not selected class

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/14b2o9ky/1/)**

Comment: I think u are adding and removing selected class  in span only not parent ,is it  correct ?

Comment: @Pete Tong Did you check my demo, is this u need ?

Answer (score 1):

Some small improvements:

`<span class="Selected"</span>` should be `<span class="selected"></span>`

(small beginning character for classes and > added)

```
$('div.large-12.columns.left.DaySelected > span').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
  e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
  $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected'); //removes all selected classes in this div
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Your `click` is binded on the `<span>`. So if you use `jQuery(this)` it is actually the span you want to change. So you dont need `.parent()` `.find()` or anything else to add the class to it.

Answer (score -2):

I think your DOM select is wrong.

```
$('div.large-12.columns.left.DaySelected > span')
```

should be

```
$('div.large-12.columns .left.DaySelected > span')
```

Comment: Nope, those classes are all on the same element so it is correct.

Comment: If you look closely you will see that there are two `div.large-12.columns` one with the class left and one without. The one he uses for the click event is correct.